# How to safely remove "old" GDATA files

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I have uninstalled the GDATA anti virus program but the files C:#GDATA.TRASH.STORE# still remain. Those files take forever to scan. How can I safely remove those files.

Answer (score 0):

The GDATA website offers a tool which claims to do exactly what you want: https://www.gdatasoftware.com/downloads

> **AVCleaner**
>
> You need this tool to completely uninstall your G DATA security solution (e.g. to reinstall it). AntiVirus Cleaner deletes from your system all remains of the program which were not removed by a simple uninstall.